# Mark object as readonly

Tags: python, database, activerecord, sqlalchemy

I am trying to emplement a user rights in my library. It looks like this.

```
class api:

def get_readonly_obj_by_id(self, user_id, obj_id) -> Obj:
    self.user_can_read_obj(user_id, obj_id) 
    return self.session.query(Obj).get(obj_id)

def save():
    self.session.commit()
```

Is it possible to mark this object as readonly?

```
obj = api.get_readonly_obj_by_id(user_id, obj_id)
obj.name = 'newName'
obj.user = new_user
api.save()
```

So all the changes made with save method wouldnt affect on this object in database.

Then i will create this method.

```
def get_write_obj_by_id(self, user_id, obj_id) -> Obj:
    self.user_can_write_obj(user_id, obj_id)
    return self.session.query(Obj).get(obj_id)
```

That will allow me to get rid of update_obj method.

```
def update_obj(self, user_id, obj_id, args: dict):
    self.user_can_write_obj(user_id=user_id, obj_id=obj_id)
    self.session.query(Obj).filter_by(id=obj_id).update(args)
    return self.session.query(Obj).get(obj_id)
```

and will allow to edit objects directly like this

```
obj.name = 'newname' # if i received this object with get_writeble_obj method
api.save()
```

Models created with ActiveRecord approuch.

Comment: What kind of protection are you looking for? Just making sure that if you accidentally try to mutate a read-only object you get an error, or preventing you from intentionally changing something no matter how hard you try?

Comment: yup. api is the class. fixed.
@abarnert 
second.
Object has 2 lists: observers and editors.
If the editor get this object from the api - that allows him to edit it ouside of the lib.
if observer - he can get object, follow the fields, but cant edit it.

Comment: You could use descriptors to raise an AttributeError when the `__set__` method is called

Comment: Well i dont exactly understand how that should work.
I should pass a tuple of (value, user_id) and then in setter check does the user with following id contains in editors?

Comment: @NChauhan Why build a custom descriptor that does the same thing as `@property` without a setter?

Comment: @abarnert If the OP wants custom behaviour rather than an `AttributeError`

Comment: @NChauhan I suppose, but you were suggesting building the same standard behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, it's relatively easy to protect values from accidental mutation, but next to impossible to protect them from intentional mutation.

---

If you just want to make it so that `obj.name = 'NewName'` will raise a `TypeError`, this is easy:

```
class MyObject:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self._frozen:
            raise TypeError(f"frozen '{type(self).__name__}' objects do not support assignment")
```

Of course you then need to go around the normal `self.name = value` mechanism to assign the values in the first place. Normally you either do this by calling `super().__setattr__` or by going straight to `self.__dict__[name]`, and often you want to do it in a `__new__` method rather than an `__init__` method. But if you're careful, you can also just do it before `self._frozen = True`.

If you need more flexibility, to freeze just some specific attributes while leaving others assignable, you can use a descriptor—the stdlib's `@property` without a `setter` works fine for this. If you also want to prevent creation of new attributes, you still need `__setattr__`—or you might want to consider using `__slots__`.

---

So, to construct an object, you might do something like this:

```
class Freezable:
    def __new__(cls, *args, frozen=False, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__setattr__(obj, '_frozen', frozen)
        return obj
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self._frozen:
            raise TypeError(f"frozen '{type(self).__name__}' objects do not support assignment")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

And now, you can just make all of your classes into subclasses of `Freezable`. They'll need to handle the `frozen` construction parameter by ignoring it in `__init__` (and explicitly passing it to `super` in `__new__`, if any of them need a custom `__new__`, but they probably won't).

Then, your `get_readonly_obj_by_id` just does something like:

```
return Whatever(user_id, obj_id, frozen=True)
```

---

But this won't stop someone from getting around the restriction if they want to. Whatever you do in your `__setattr__`, they can do directly. Or, if you're using a `@property` to store the value elsewhere, they can just assign to that elsewhere. Not to mention that they can just set `obj,_frozen = False`. (You can make them jump through the same hoops again, but that doesn't make it any more secure.)

If you have some other storage that *is* protected, you can always change your objects into some kind of proxy to that storage, instead of holding the values directly, but that's pretty complicated—and it relies on you having already built some kind of protected store; it isn't a way to build one in the first place.

---

Your database presumably *is* just such a protected store. But you don't want to proxy every attribute lookup and assignment through the database—in fact, you don't want anything written there at all until `save`.

But that means a hybrid approach is probably fine.

Use the "consenting adults" protection of `__setattr__` and `_frozen` to protect people from accidentally mutating an object they won't be allowed to store.

If they go behind your back and find a way to mutate the object anyway, when they call `save`, you can block the update (or the database can do it automatically for you) and give them an exception.

Comment: I guess that will be enough. Thanks a lot. Also this will make for me to much easier to implement other features.

Comment: Well. That works as expected but i found out that i need some lists inside this. So append methods works on it. 
Probably i have try to mark my objects as readonly via orm solutions

Comment: @TorSen If you want to get clever, you can use a `__getattribute__` that turns list attributes into tuples, or returns copies instead of the original values, or returns proxy wrappers (copying the `_frozen` flag) for every attribute, or…

Comment: @TorSen But it may be simpler to change your API so that instead of exposing a `thingies` list, you expose methods to access and modify (subject to `_frozen`) the thingies. It's pretty hard to say whether that's a good idea without a more complete example.